# OnLoad property not working in the better-react-mathjax library

Tags: reactjs, mathjax

I'm using the onload property that better-mathjax-react library offers to signal the component that the display of the equation has finished, but this propoerty doesn't work for some reason, so how to solve this problem?

This is the component responsible for displaying the texts:

```
const myComponent= (props) => {

  const config = {
    tex2jax: {
      inlineMath: [
        ["$", "$"],
        ["\\(", "\\)"],
      ],
      displayMath: [
        ["$$", "$$"],
        ["\\[", "\\]"],
      ],
      processEscapes: true,
    },
  };

  return (
          <MathJaxContext
            onLoad={() => {
              console.log(
                "the equation display should end here, but this function never gets called"
              );
            }}
            config={config}
            version={2}
            hideUntilTypeset="first"
          >
            <MathJax inline>{"$" + props.expression.word + "$"}</MathJax>
          </MathJaxContext>
      )}
```

Comment: I've answered this on the project website (https://github.com/fast-reflexes/better-react-mathjax/issues/50). It looks like you're using one `MathJaxContext` in every component where MathJax is used? This is not the intended use. Instead, wrap your entire app in ONE `MathJaxContext` and it should work well.